# Bevelling a curve so the diameter gets smaller

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I'm trying to model this[image], which is the internal mold of a seashell. I use the Curve Extra addons to make a spiral and a bevel the curve with a circle. The thing is that the diameteris supposed to get thinner and thinner, and I don't know how to do it but manually (and it's not very good beacause I can't tweak the parameters.
Any help welcome ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferably after you enable the curve bevel, so you can see in real time the effect, <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> edit the curve, select a point on one side, <kbd>O</kbd> enable proportional editing, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> scale the radius, and $\color{#888}{█}\color{green}⬆\color{#888}{█}$ *mouse wheel up* to increase the influence range:

[image]

On the GIF above you can perhaps notice how the curve doesn't thicken nicely along its path, this is because the *"Connected"* option was not enabled, consider enabling it, as well as try other falloffs:

[image]

Comment: Hi ! (and I noticed I was to focused on explaining my issue and didn't say hi, how rude, sorry) Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know about the influence range